# Is it possible to connect an iPhone to a WiFi network that you've previously connected your Mac to without having to enter the password on the phone?

Tags: macos, iphone, icloud, wifi, password

I'm pretty sure that iCloud will sync Wi-Fi information from your iPhone to your Mac, but I've connected to a network with a "secure" password and typing it on my phone is a pain.  Can I use the fact that I've connected to the network on my Mac to have the iPhone connect without wasting time entering the password on the phone?

In case it helps, it's an iPhone 6 with iOS9 and a 2009 MacBook Pro with El Capitan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as iCloud keychain goes, it will save a lot of your passwords that you enter on websites (as well as usernames) but I don't believe it will do it for wifi passwords.

Once you enter the password once on your iPhone though, it should remember it from then on, so you will not have to enter it each time.

Comment: I'll need to file a bug to Apple that iCloud Keychain doesn't support WiFi network passwords, then.